# Django API Rest Framework and Angular 7 Authentication with jwt token

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using Django Rest Framework for the back-end and Angular 7 for the user interface. I'm trying to create a login page to my single page application and authenticate with a jwt token. I've already managed the back-end and it works. Whenever i go to /api-token-auth/ and type the credentials i get a token in the rest framework interface. 
The front-end part though troubles me. I have created the login component, the authorization  service and a token interceptor. I believe i did the right adjustments but whenever i try to login from angular this error appears in the django command promt.

> "Bad Request: /api-token-auth/ [19/Nov/2018 20:16:16] "POST
>   /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 400 68 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
>       self.finish_response()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
>       self.write(data)   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
>       self.send_headers()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
>       self.send_preamble()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
>       ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')   File
>   "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
>       result = self.stdout.write(data)   File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
>       self._sock.sendall(b) ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine [19/Nov/2018 20:16:16] "POST /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
>   ---------------------------------------- Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51566) Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in
>   run
>       self.finish_response()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
>       self.write(data)   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
>       self.send_headers()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
>       self.send_preamble()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
>       ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')   File
>   "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
>       result = self.stdout.write(data)   File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
>       self._sock.sendall(b) ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
>       self.handle_error()   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line
>   86, in handle_error
>       super().handle_error()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
>       self.finish_response()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
>       self.write(data)   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
>       self.send_headers()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
>       if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
>       return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "C:\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in **init**
>       self.handle()   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line
>   154, in handle
>       handler.run(self.server.get_app())   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
>       self.close()   File "C:\Python36\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
>       self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"

I'm really trying to understand what is going on based in this error. Anybody has an idea? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I had never imported the FormsModuls and apparently that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
line 35, in close self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Due to some reason, the attribute **self.status** is returning **None** which cannot be split, thus, causing errors.

Comment: Apparently the problem was the FormsModule which was not imported in my app.module.ts. Thanks for your answer